# Regex to remove bit signal noise spikes

Tags: python, regex

I am dealing with RF signals that sometimes have noise spikes.
The input is something like this:
`00000001111100011110001111100001110000001000001111000000111001111000`

Before parsing the data in the signal, I need to remove the spike bits, that are 0's and 1's sequence with a lenght lower than (in this example) 3.

So basically I need to match `0000000111110001111000111110000111000000(1)000001111000000111(00)1111000`

After match, I replace it by the bit before it, so a clean signal look like this:
`00000001111100011110001111100001110000000000001111000000111111111000`

So far I achieved this with two different Regex:

```
self.re_one_spikes = re.compile("(?:[^1])(?P<spike>1{1,%d})(?=[^1])" % (self._SHORTEST_BIT_LEN - 1))
self.re_zero_spikes = re.compile("(?:[^0])(?P<spike>0{1,%d})(?=[^0])" % (self._SHORTEST_BIT_LEN - 1))
```

Then I iterate on the matches and replace.

How can I do this with a single regex? And can I use regex to replace different sizes matches?
I tried something like this with no success:

```
re.compile("(?![\1])([01]{1,2})(?![\1])")
```

Comment: So, you basically want to replace any isolated single or double 1 or 0 with 0 or 1 respectively?

Comment: Yes, not necessarily single or doubles, but lower than a specific size.

Comment: Also, what's wrong with two regex? If you don't like the code duplication (valid point) you could use a single template string and substitute the 0 and 1 into that.

Comment: What if the string is `00000110011001100111111`? What to replace?

Comment: There is nothing wrong using the two regex, just think there might be a better way to achieve this.

Comment: @tobias_k ... after **3** passes with my code `'00000000000111111111111'` :P

Comment: In the @tobias_k examples, probably the signal would be ruined already :)

Comment: @joaoricardo000 : Added an alternative approach to achieve this without using regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import re
THRESHOLD=3

def fixer(match):
    ones = match.group(0)
    if len(ones) < THRESHOLD: return "0"*len(ones)
    return ones

my_string = '00000001111100011110001111100001110000001000001111000000111001111000'
print(re.sub("(1+)",fixer,my_string))
```

if you want to also remove "spikes" of zeros

```
def fixer(match):
    items = match.group(0)
    if len(items) < THRESHOLD: return "10"[int(items[0])]*len(items)
    return items

print(re.sub("(1+)|(0+)",fixer,my_string))
```

Comment: Nice and simple, but it seems like OP also wants to remove "spikes" of zeros. But that could be adapted accordingly.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @joaoricardo000 i think you should address tobias_k's comment on your question ... depending on how you answer that it might get a whole lot more complicated :/

Answer (score 1):

To match both cases `[01]`in a single regex, it's simply this:

`(?<=([01]))(?:(?!\1)[01]){1,2}(?=\1)`

Expanded

```
 (?<=                 # Lookbehind for 0 or 1
      ( [01] )             # (1), Capture behind 0 or 1
 )
 (?:                  # Match spike, one to %d times in length
      (?! \1 )             # Cannot be the 0 or 1 from lookbehind
      [01] 
 ){1,2}
 (?= \1 )             # Lookahead, can only be 0 or 1 from capture (1)
```

Replace with `$1` times length of the match ( i.e. length of group 0 ).

Matches

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 40 , len 1 ) 
1  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 39 , len 1 ) 
0  

----------------------------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 59 , len 2 ) 
00  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 58 , len 1 ) 
1
```

Benchmark

```
Regex1:   (?<=([01]))(?:(?!\1)[01]){1,2}(?=\1)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    2.06 s,   2058.02 ms,   2058018 µs


50,000 iterations * 2 matches/iteration = 100,000 matches 

100,000 matches / 2 sec's  =  50,000 matches per second
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach without using `regex`, and by using `replace()` instead (in case someone might find it useful in future):

```
>>> my_signal = '00000001111100011110001111100001110000001000001111000000111001111000'
>>> my_threshold = 3
>>> for i in range(my_threshold):
...     my_signal = my_signal.replace('0{}0'.format('1'*(i+1)), '0{}0'.format('0'*(i+1)))
... 
>>> my_signal
'00000001111100011110001111100000000000000000001111000000000001111000'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fix_noise(s, noise_thold=3):
    pattern=re.compile(r'(?P<before>1|0)(?P<noise>(?<=0)1{1,%d}(?=0)|(?<=1)0{1,%d}(?=1))' % (noise_thold-1, noise_thold-1))
    result = s
    for noise_match in pattern.finditer(s):
        beginning = result[:noise_match.start()+1]
        end = result[noise_match.end():]
        replaced = noise_match.group('before')*len(noise_match.group('noise'))
        result = beginning + replaced + end
    return result
```

Jordan's `int(items[0])` indexing idea is awesome!